# h:button not passing f:param from a JSF component

Tags: jsf, param

I have a JSF 2 page with an `<h:button>`.  I want to pass two `<f:param>` to the outcome page.

Value of `<f:param>` pOne comes from the page bean.
Value of `<f:param>` pTwo comes from an input field on the page.

pTwo's value is *not* stored on the page bean.
pTwo's input field value is set by javascript when user clicks on an image map within same page.

**The problem is that the request passes null for param pTwo.**

If I set the value of pTwo to a static value, value="12345", then 12345 is passed.

So, why does `<f:param>` not pass the value of a input field from the source page?

Thanks!

`<input type="text" id="pTwo"/>
 <h:button value="Go" outcome="destPage">
    <f:param name="pOne" value=#{myBean.pOne}"/>
    <f:param name="pTwo" value=#{pTwo}"/>
</h:button>`

Comment: Please paste the relevant xhtml code here. Are you using `<h:inputText>` or really using that `<input>`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference the value of the input field in an  EL expression like this. Not even if you use `h:inputText`.

Furthermore, JSF calculates the link for the button including the parameters when the page is rendered on server side. So when the user sees the page and enters something in the input field, the URL for the link is already fixed and won't change.

To solve this in a similar way, you could use `h:commandButton` instead of `h:button`, submit the form including the value for `pTwo`with `h:inputText` and return a redirect to the new page. The XHTML for this could look like this:

```
<h:form>
  <h:inputText value="#{bean.pTwo}"/>
  <h:commandButton action="#{bean.goToDest}" value="Go"/>
</h:form>
```

The referenced action method could look like this:

```
public String goToDest() {
  return "destPage?faces-redirect=true&pOne=" + pOne + "&pTwo=" + pTwo;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I had overlooked that the input component was already set to the empty string during the lifecycle.  Although the user can change the displayed value via Javascript, this has no relation to the component which was already rendered.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try use the following code:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.goToDest}" value="Go" >
   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{yourDestinyManagedBean.pOne}" value="#{yourManagedBean.pOne}" />
   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{youDestinyManagedBean.pTwo}" value="#{yourManagedBean.pTwo}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

You can see an example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-setpropertyactionlistener-example/).